# Spark: how to group together one column of elements based on other two columns of elements in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I hava an RDD with 3 columns (road_idx, snodeidx,enodeidx).
It looks like this:

```
(roadidx_995, 1138, 1145)
(roadidx_996, 1138, 1139)
(roadidx_997, 2740, 1020)
(roadidx_998, 2762, 2740)
(roadidx_999, 3251, 3240)
.........
```

How to group together road_idx which have one of the snodeidx or enodeidx in common? Give each group a number starts from 1.

expected output:

```
(1,[roadidx_995,roadidx_996])
(2,[roadidx_997,roadidx_998])
(3,[roadidx_999])
```

as shown above,

roadidx_995 and roadidx_996 have the same **snodeidx** 1138.

roadidx_997 has the **snodeidx** the same as the **enodeidx** of roadidx_998 which is 2740.

roadidx_999 is in a group on its own.

Scala code or Python code are both ok. As long as you can tell me the logic of using RDD APIs to get the expected output.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi did you find a solution on this one?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis No, i changed the method. Still can't find a computation-cost-saving way to do it

Comment: Hello, I think you need to find another way to align your data. The way you represent the data at the moment is very complicated and that is the reason you can not find a solution for it. Try to split up your data in a different way and find an alternative to express the relations between your entities.

Answer (score -1):

Can be implemented as:

1. Split original on two rdd - grouped by "start" and "end" node.
2. Join original dataset with values from 1) several times, and get four columns like:

   ```
   |------------------|----------------|--------------|----------------|
   | start join start | start join end | end join end | end join start |
   |------------------|----------------|--------------|----------------|
   ```
3. Join values from four columns in one

On Scala can be implemented:

```
val data = List(
  ("roadidx_995", 1138, 1145),
  ("roadidx_996", 1138, 1139),
  ("roadidx_997", 2740, 1020),
  ("roadidx_998", 2762, 2740),
  ("roadidx_999", 3251, 3240)
)
val original = sparkContext.parallelize(data)

val groupedByStart = original.map(v => (v._1, v._2)).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))
val groupedByEnd = original.map(v => (v._1, v._3)).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))
val indexesOnly = original.map(allRow => (allRow._2, allRow._3))

// join by start value
val startJoinsStart = indexesOnly.keyBy(_._1).join(groupedByStart)
val startJoinsEnd = startJoinsStart.leftOuterJoin(groupedByEnd)

// join by end value
val endKeys = startJoinsEnd.values.keyBy(_._1._1._2)

val endJoinsEnd = endKeys.join(groupedByEnd)
val endJoinsStart = endJoinsEnd.leftOuterJoin(groupedByStart)

// flatten to output format
val result = endJoinsStart
  .values
  .map(v => (v._1._1._1._2, v._1._1._2, v._1._2, v._2))
  .map(v => v._1 ++ v._2.getOrElse(Seq()) ++ v._3 ++ v._4.getOrElse(Seq()))
  .map(_.toSet)
  .distinct()

result.foreach(println)
```

Output is:

```
Set(roadidx_995, roadidx_996)
Set(roadidx_998, roadidx_997)
Set(roadidx_999)
```